# Boost thread local storage in Windows threads

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost

I tried to use [Boost thread local storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html) with Windows threads. I built the project without any problems.

However my question here is, is it okay to use Boost TLS with Windows threads?

Comment: It's not clear, at least to me, what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Yes Boost is integrally supported on windows with all major compilers:

**[Supported compilers and platforms](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/supported_compilers.html)**

> The library should build and work with a reasonably compliant compiler. The library was > successfully built and tested on the following platforms:
>
> - Windows XP, Windows Vista. MSVC 8.0, 9.0. MSVC 7.1 may work too, but it was not tested.
> - Windows Vista. Intel C++ Compiler 10.1.022, 11.1.048.
> - Linux. GCC 4.2 and newer. GCC 4.1 may work too, but it was not tested.
> - Linux. Intel C++ 11.1.056.
>
> The following compilers/platforms are not supported and will likely fail to compile the library:
>
> - MSVC 7.0 and older.
> - Borland C++ 5.5.1 (free version). Newer versions might or might not work.
> - GCC 4.0 and older.
> - Windows 9x, ME, NT4 and older are not supported.

---

<sub><strike>I suppose you mean what "libraries do I need"?</strike></sub>

You need to link to the import library for boost threads, usually a file like

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boot_1_47_0\lib\libboost_pthread....lib
```

This file can be added to the additional libraries to link box in the c++ linker settings. Don't forget to add it for debug and release builds.

PS. don't have Windows handy right now, so I can't do the screen shots.

Comment: No. I mean that I have all libraries and I have successfully built and started the project. My point here is that ok to use BOOST TLS with windows threads?

Comment: Um. Of course? See [Supported compilers and platforms](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/supported_compilers.html) (editing answer)